# Magento 2 : Adding logo in a custom extension

Tags: magento2, custom, magento-2.1.9, logo

I'm creating an extension where I should be able to call the logo which has been uploaded to Magento to show up in the home page.

So I upload the logo to:

> Content -> Design -> Configuration -> Edit (Global) -> Header -> Logo Image

[image]

I have been investigating how Magento calls the logo:

> vendor/magento/module-theme/Block/Html/Header/Logo.php

What would I need to add to my custom module in order to get this logo and show it. Thank you.

Comment: Did you try my solution? did it work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to inject  `\Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Header\Logo` class in your block/controller and call `getLogoSrc()` method on its object to get the logo url and `getLogoAlt()` to get alt text.

Once you have it you can show it image tag in a phtml.

You can see a relevant tutorial here - https://www.mageplaza.com/how-get-logo-url-alt-text-logo-size-magento-2.html